# Name for design pattern used in complex or boolean search criteria

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns, search, terminology

I am looking to see if there is a term that describes this type of design pattern or if there are well known examples of its implementation.

This is an extension of the design pattern where a search term is entered into an input field and becomes a filter/criteria for a search query (e.g. e-commerce website) or tagging of an entity (e.g. UXSE question).

In the diagram below, there are two input fields from which a user can select a combination of the values provided in each list (and it might have some logic embedded depending on the value selected). The values are then combined and presented as a lozenge/badge/chip UI element that can be selected and deleted.

[image]

Are there examples of this type of design pattern used anywhere? And is there a name that is commonly associated with it?

Comment: Hi Michael! I'm not sure I really understand correctly what are you searching for, but this seems to be a common custom filter. You can check this functionality here, on stackexchange, when you can save/ apply a custom filter for the questions where A is "filter by" (no answers, no accepted answer, has bounty), B is "Sorted by" (newest, most votes,...) and C is "Tagged with".

Comment: @MadalinaTaina the general feature is common, but the criteria is normally a single filter instead of something that is a combination of filters (as encapsulated by the badges/lozenges in the screenshot). So normally you see individual filters (e.g. Value A1, Value B2) rather than combined filters (e.g. Value A1 + Value B3). Hope this helps to clarify the question for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think adding custom filters that are usually a combination of sorting and filtering is known as "Faceted search" technique.

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search), this is defined as:

> a technique which involves augmenting traditional search techniques
>   with a faceted navigation system, allowing users to narrow down the search
>   results by applying multiple filters based on faceted classification
>   of the items. A faceted classification system classifies each
>   information element along multiple explicit dimensions called facets,
>   enabling the classifications to be accessed and ordered in multiple
>   ways rather than in a single, pre-determined, taxonomic order.

Like I said in comments, an example is how you search a type of questions on ux.stackexchange.
[image]

I like the clarification on [Nielsen Norman Group](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/filters-vs-facets/):

> Filter means anything that analyzes a set of content and excludes some
>   items. Faceted navigation is composed of multiple filters that
>   comprehensively describe a set of content.

[image]

They have some good examples there and the article is a great read, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it's depend of type and category of this value.

You mention that a lozenge/badge/chip ui elements can be selected - so it's important to mark, which is selected, which not.

This is similar to filters.It's depend of data set, which filters would be optimal.

If your interface will further develop, You can consider introduction on the left, an element with filters, and display results in the middle section:

[image]

On the selection criteria i see scope (from A1 to B3)
If this for example Price, where user need to select MIN-MAX - it's great to use **UI SLIDER**  [image]

And also a process of adding criteria? How it works? 
Is sense to the user? he chooses criteria from some drop down list?

---

EDIT:

Jira displays commonly used parameters on UI and user has the option to add more parameters from available list.

[image]

Comment: I am mainly interested to know if you have seen any examples of this type of design pattern, and what it might be called. There are some good ideas for improving the design pattern based on more specific user requirements, but that would be in a different question.

Comment: I have not come across this kind of settings unless filters 
or other methods of limiting the data visible on the screen.